# Expectation conditional on a sum of random variables

Tags: econometrics, probability

The setting is a simple OLS regression where the true model has regressor $x$ and error term $u$, but we can only measure $\bar{x}=x+v$ where $v$ is iid with mean 0.

According to the textbook:

$\mathbb{E}(u|x)=0$ is satisfied, but $\mathbb{E}(\bar{u}|\bar{x})=\mathbb{E}(u-\beta x|x+v)=-\beta v$

I can see that $x$ and $u$ are correlated, but why am I allowed to just take $\beta x$ out of the expectation when I "only" condition on the sum $x+v$, and not explicitly on $v$?